# Databases: What is a HANA delta table?

Tags: sql, database, hana

What is a delta table in SAP HANA databases?

From initial googling, I understood that these tables are some kind of intermediate tables to help data go from one state to another. But when exactly are they used? How are they different from "normal" tables in HANA databases?

Comment: “Delta table” can have many meanings; please post an example or context we are to base an answer on.

Answer (score 2):

Delta tables are a SAP-HANA specific technique to speed up write operations in the database.

Tables in SAP HANA usually use the column store, which is read-optimized. When writing data to a column-store table, this data is first stored in the delta-space for that table; this delta-space is periodically merged into the column store.

See e.g. https://cookbook.experiencesaphana.com/bw/operating-bw-on-hana/hana-database-administration/system-configuration/delta-merge/column-store/ for more details.

Answer (score -1):

"Delta" is commonly used to mean "difference". A delta table would show only the differences between two tables, the records that were added/deleted/changed during the new process. It's a way to test new code to see what changes it caused.